# PHP isset not picking up url passed parameter

Tags: php, include, parameter-passing, isset

I'm using the following code in the file main.php:

```
searchpage = "index.php?k=SEARCH";
include($searchpage);
```

To call code within index:

```
if(isset($k)){
    $k = $_GET['k'];   
    if ($k =="SEARCH"){
      include("searchpage.php");
    }
  }
```

By my understanding this should insert the contents of the file searchpage.php where I called

```
include($searchpage);
```

However it just loads main.php again, meaning that k was not set. How does passing ?k=var work in regards to isset() and why does isset reading k as null when I put k=SEARCH in the url when calling the page?

If you need more of the code for context or clarity for the question please let me know thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think $k is not set so PHP doesn't go into the "if clause":

```
  if(isset($_GET['k'])){
        $k = $_GET['k'];   
        if ($k == "SEARCH"){
          include("searchpage.php");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow that fixed it except, that was meant to be skeletal code for an assignment. Was there anywhere on the other end that could have fixed this or is the given code(what was changed) inherently wrong?

Answer (score 0):

main.php

```
$k="search";
include "index.php";
```

index.php

```
if ($k=="search") {
    include "searchpage.php";
}
```

Sorry, I might be missing your point, but from the logic of your code, this is simpler and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this `$searchpage = "index.php?k=SEARCH";`

If you want to pass parameter you have to pass it from url i.e from address bar only.

So pass parameter in address bar and then include your index.php like this

```
$searchpage = "index.php";
```

Then your code wil work fine

Hope this will help you.

Comment: the lines " $homepage = "index.php?k= ";
  $searchpage = "index.php?k=SEARCH";" are part of the skeletal code I was given and have to use. If I cannot use the code and cannot find anywhere on this site how to use the address to pass parameters then I am lost.

Comment: Which two lines?

I want to say that if your current page url is `www.somedomain.com` change it with `www.somedomain.com?k=SEARCH`

It will definitely work fine

If you still have any problem just comment here

Comment: Sorry I just found out I cant start a new line in a comment, I edited my comment for more clarity.

Comment: You have to do it just find it from where you are redirecting and give it parameters or do it using some jquery. or you can do one thing instead of `$searchpage = "index.php?k=SEARCH"` just use `$searchpage = "index.php" ` and in next line use `$k=SEARCH"` then in your index.php check for $k instead of $_GET.